# Neither this nor that

Tags: logic

If I've understood things correctly, I can get `true` from "Is this true or that true"? with a simple double pipe:

```
true || false
```

But is there any more succinct way to get `true` on the question "Is neither this true nor that true" than the following?

```
false == false && false == false
```

Comment: I would think *Is this true or that true* would be `This || That`, and *Is neither this true nor that true* would be `not This && not That`. The reason being that "nor" is really an AND of the two negations, in English semantics. If you said, "I neither smoke, nor do I drink" it means both "not smoke" and "not drink" are true. You can think of it as a negation of the OR: `not (This || That)` is equivalent to `not This && not That`. I'm not sure what you're attempting to do with the use of literal `true` and `false` in your expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but "neither this true nor that true" means both should be `false` - which is the *opposite* of "is this true or that true", so if the first is:

```
a || b
```

the second would be the *negation* of the first:

```
!(a || b)
```

Here is the truth table for this:

```
a\b  | true  | false
---------------------
true | false | false
     |       |
false| false | true
     |       |
```

So, this will return `true` if and only if both `a` *and* `b` are false.